# Tried with Ionic Login but Input Password field was totally skipped Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line, ionic3, ionic-native

[The input password field was skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NRsD.png)

I've new icon and splashscreen to replace the original ionic icon and splashscreen. When I tried with command "ionic cordova resources". It requested me to have done ionic login first. However, when I entered my registered ionic account, I wasn't given any chances to input my account password. The operating system that I'm using is Windows 10. This problem doesn't exist when I using my macbook. Does anyone have any solutions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u meet the condition like me. Just simply type ionic login "email" "password" to login. You may refer to the documentation here https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/login/